# Load content in Reactjs in a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to show something inside of my modal with react-bootstrap. I know you can import the component something like this:

```
    Modal.Dialog>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>

  <Modal.Body>
    <MyComponent/>
  </Modal.Body>

  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
    <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal.Dialog>
```

My doubt is if i cant do it by url with react, something like Jquery do it with .load() and 
instead of `<MyComponent/>`  could be something like: `$( ".ModalBody ).load( "MyComponent-url" );`

I dont know if is possible do it with React, in that case this could be a bad practice? Thank you for any help!

Comment: that should work fine, whats the issue? what isnt working, what errors do you have?

Comment: My issue is if i cant do it with React, i dont want use jquery!

Comment: why cant you? what isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, u should avoid using jQuery anyway. Use of component way is more correct than using jQuery. Or in simple words avoid using Jquery as much as possible